# how to fix this class definition in javascript to support instanceof operator

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a class definition method for create class in javascript:

```
var Class = function() {
    var clazz = null,
    pros = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var arg = arguments[i];
        if (typeof arg == "function") arg = arg.prototype;
        else {
            arg.init && (clazz = arg.init, delete arg.init)
        }
        for (var p in arg) pros[p] = arg[p];
    }
    clazz.prototype = pros;
    return clazz;
};

var Person = Class({
    init: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    say:function(){
        console.info(this.name);
    }
});

var Man = Class(Person, {
    init: function(name) {
        Person.apply(this, arguments);
        this.gender = 'man'
    }
});

var m = new Man('kk');
console.info(m instanceof Man);
console.info(m instanceof Person);
```

However, it does not support the `instanceof` operator.

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: this explains how instanceof works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: Or here: http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.6

Comment: I read this. And I try change 'arg=arg.prototype' to 'arg=new arg()'. It does not work.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Your script appears to run perfectly fine.  Do you get an error message?

Comment: There is no error in the code. But I want `console.info(m instanceof Person)` return true while it is false now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep track of the prototype chain to make `instanceof` work. What you're currently doing is merely copying properties into *one* object, and use that as prototype of the returned function. As a result, the information that `Parent` is a parent of `Man` is lost.

You'd need to set the prototype instead of copying. <s>Since you need to modify an existing object to set the underlying prototype of, the deprecated `__proto__` property is required. `Object.create` cannot be used here, because that returns a new object.</s>

**Edit:** It is possible without `__proto__`, but you'd need the `function F` trick: http://jsfiddle.net/p9pvQ/.

```
var clazz = null,
    pros = Object.prototype; // root of chain

for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];

    if (typeof arg === "function") {
        arg = arg.prototype;
    } else {
        if(arg.init) {
            clazz = arg.init;
            delete arg.init;
        }
        var o = arg;
        arg = (function() { function F() {}; F.prototype = pros; return new F; })();
        for(var key in o) arg[key] = o[key];
    }

    pros = arg;
}
```

`m` will then have the prototype chain as follows:

```
Class.init // m
  gender: "man"
  name: "kk"
  __proto__: F // Man
    __proto__: F // Person
      say: function (){
      __proto__: Object // Object.prototype
        __defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
        __defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
        ... (Object.prototype functions)
```

Comment: `arg.__proto__ = pros;` I notice this line. I wonder if this work in IE?

Comment: @hguser: Looks like it doesn't. I've no idea how to do it without, though. Let me do some little bit more research on this.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. In fact it is not limited to my exist code. I just want a class definition method,and I do not there are some endless prototype chain.

Comment: Also I have tried to replace `arg.__proto__ = pros` to `arg= inherit(pros);`. Where the inherit is like this:`function inherit(pro){
 function F(){};
 F.prototype=pro;
 return new F();
}`

Comment: @hguser: The prototype chain is required to make `instanceof` work as far as I'm concerned. Without the correct chain, there are no true instances.

Comment: @hguser: Seems like I managed to accomplish it without `__proto__`, using the `function F` trick. Please see my edit.

Comment: :BTW,why it does not work if I use the 'inherit' method then we have to use the self-execute function?